# Change start button to pause button

Tags: android

I want to use a stop watch in my app. So I try this tutorial but what I need are two changes and I can't really figure them out.

I found a bug that when I press start and then again it will start again. So what I want is a start button that will change into a pause button when pressed and visa versa. How can I switch the buttons?

My layout for the buttons is this:

```
<Button

android:id=”@+id/btnPause”
android:layout_width=”90dp”
android:layout_marginLeft=”20dp”
android:layout_height=”45dp”
android:layout_centerVertical=”true”
android:layout_toRightOf=”@+id/btnStart”
android:text=”Pause” />

<Button
android:id=”@+id/btnStart”
android:layout_width=”90dp”
android:layout_height=”45dp”

android:layout_alignParentLeft=”true”
android:layout_centerVertical=”true”
android:layout_marginLeft=”68dp”
android:text=”Start” />
```

The class is this:

```
package com.androidituts.stopwatch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StopwatchActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private TextView textTimer;
private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMillies = 0L;
long timeSwap = 0L;
long finalTime = 0L;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);

startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);

}
});

pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
timeSwap += timeInMillies;
myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);

}
});

}

private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

public void run() {
timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() – startTime;
finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
textTimer.setText(“” + minutes + “:”
+ String.format(“%02d”, seconds) + “:”
+ String.format(“%03d”, milliseconds));
myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}

};

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did the same thing with a button that toggled everytime you pressed it. here is how i did it

declare a `int state = 1`

the state means the functionality and the appearance of the button that would be. lets say `1` is `start` `2` is `pause` and `3` is `stop`(just for the tutorial purpose).

set the default state (in this case 1) and accordingly set the background

check the state everytime in the `onclicklistener` if the state is 1 implement the corresponding functionality, change the button background to pause and change the state to 2, and similarly for the rest of the others

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

you can change text of button yourself, or you should try [Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make one of the buttons visible then just toggle the visibility from `View.VISIBLE` to `View.GONE` and do the opposite for the other button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {

if(startButton.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
}

else if(startButton.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Pause")) {
timeSwap += timeInMillies;
myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
}
}
});
```